# In model validation not defined but on execution it is validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC project. In Model, I have defined some properties.

```
public string Org { get; set; }
public string Design { get; set; }
```

For these two properties, I have not define any validation attribute like `[Required(ErrorMessage=.....)]` but still on execution it is validate.

> jquery.validate.min.js
>
> jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>
> jquery.form.js

above iqueries I am using.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get rid of Required messages, you can apply this code in application_start()

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

If you want to get rid of data annotation support all together(See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458417/can-i-disable-dataannotations-validation-on-defaultmodelbinder)): `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();`